# whats wrong with this JS? should be quick fix

Tags: javascript

Just not sure why this doesn't work? the prompt work but nothing after.

```
function btn(){
    prompt('do you like banana?');

    if("yes"){
        alert = "good";
    }
    else {
        alert =  "to bad, try again!";
    }
};
```

Comment: You're prompting the user, but you're not checking the prompt response with your if statement. You should store the `prompt` response into a variable, and then your if statement conditional should check if the `prompt === "yes"`. Also, the `alert` function should be invoked like so: `alert("good")`

Comment: `alert` is  a function. You should call it not override it! `alert('...')`

Comment: Stack Overflow's [JavaScript tag info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info) has links to a number of tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

Just condensing Sabar's answer and changing `alert = ...` to the method version (which I'm guessing is what you wanted), it could also be written as:

With a `prompt()`, which would return what the user enters (random is possible)

```
function btn(){
    if(prompt('do you like banana?') == "yes"){
        alert("good");
    } else {
        alert("to bad, try again!");
    }
};
```

Or with a `confirm()`

```
function btn(){
    if(confirm('Would you like banana?')){
        alert("good");
    } else {
        alert("to bad, try again!");
    }
};
```

You could take it even further if you like with:

```
function btn(){
    confirm('Would you like banana?') ? alert("good") : alert("to bad, try again!");
};
```

Or even one step more into the realm of harder to read (as suggested by nnnnnn)

```
function btn(){
    alert(confirm('Would you like banana?') ? "good" : "to bad, try again!");
};
```

Comment: If you're going to take it further, why not go all the way: `alert(confirm('Would you like banana?') ? "Good" : "Too bad, try again!");`

Comment: @nnnnnn : I thought about it, but some readability is important to me.

Comment: @sosro: Mark this answer as correct answer. As, the user has helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the value of prompt to a variable:

```
function btn(){ 
  var response = prompt('do you like banana?');
  if(response == "yes"){
      alert("good");
  }
  else {
      alert("too bad, try again!");
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

prompt is a function which returns what the user typed, so

```
function btn(){ 

userAnswer = prompt('do you like banana?');

if(userAnswer === "yes"){
    alert("good");
}
else {
    alert("to bad, try again!");
}
};
```

this should work.
Also, alert is a function, and by writing alert = "asdad", you are instead making it just a string. Also, if("yes") just checks if the string "yes" is evaluated to true or false, and it is always evaluated to false. You may want to take a look at some online course for Javascript, for example [this](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Prompt returns null if you have cancelled it, and it select value from textbox if you select ok.

```
  function btn(){
   var response = prompt('do you like banana?',"yes");
   if(response){
      alert("good");
   }
   else {
     alert("too bad, try again!");
   }
 };
```

Comment: The OP is trying to test for a response of "yes". Your code would display the same alert for "no" and "yes".

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure what you want is a prompt?
From your code i understand that it's a confirm.

```
function btn() {

        var r = window.confirm("do you like banana?");
        if (r == true) {
            alert("good");
        } else {
            alert("to bad, try again!");
        }

    };
```

If you want a prompt then use this:

```
function btn() {

        var r = prompt("do you like banana?", "I'm a monkey!!!");
        if (r != null) {
            alert("good. " + r);//good. I'm a monkey!!!
        }
        else
            alert("to bad, try again!");

    };
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be a bit strange to reply "good" to any (non-empty) answer?

Comment: "good", "to bad, try again", "do you like banana?" , these are texts from his example. I kept his texts so he can understand better the code flow.